# Why does CodeIgniter 4's anchor() utilize site_url() format (with indexPage) instead of base_url() (without indexPage)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-7, codeigniter-4

`anchor()` generates links with `indexPage` appended e.g. `http://example.com/index.php/news/local/123`.
Wouldn't it be prettier (SEO-wise) to not have the indexPage? e.g. `http://example.com/news/local/123` like `base_url()` does? What would be the downside(s) of doing so?

Is there an option to configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app\Config\App.php set

```
public $indexPage = '';
```

and your problem is solved.